# Socket that listens for everything

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a computer on my network that had multiple IP addresses and uses multiple ports. Is there any way to open a socket that receives data on all those ip addresses and all those ports, and then have the data received contain the ip address from the packet header, and the port it received it on?

Rephrase:
How can I set up a socket that can receive data on multiple ports and IPs?
Then once I receive the data, is there any way to know where the data came from?

Comment: If you listen on the special IP address `0.0.0.0`, the socket will bind to all interfaces.

Comment: Listening on "multiple ports" isn't TCP -- perhaps you should capture raw IP packets. A library like `libpcap` should be useful for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = array();
for(i = 1; i <= 65535; i++) {
    s[i] = socket.listen_port(i);
    fwrite('file.dat', s[i].read()."\n");
}
```

Ofcourse in your programing language. Thats idea only.
Dont forget, that if port already used by another application, you wont be able to read or write to it - i think so...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot bind to multiple ports using just one socket. The TCP/IP networking stack is based on the idea that one port == one socket.

Answer (score 3):

To listen on all IP adresses just use INADDR_ANY. However you *will* still need one socket per port.